# Why can't I call any hardware methods in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, light

I am trying to turn the torch of the iOS device on and off in my Swift app.

By looking at the documentation, I can see that `lockForConfiguration()`, `setTorchModeOn(1.0)`, and `unlockForConfiguration()`are what I need to call.

However, these methods are apparently `not in scope`. My first thought was that these methods were for `Objective-C`, but the documentation shows that these methods are in fact, for Swift.

I am maybe calling these methods incorrectly. However, from what I see I can call these methods raw (No parent script/class).

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
    }
    
    func turnTorchOn() {
        lockForConfiguration()
        setTorchModeOn(1.0)
        unlockForConfiguration()
    }
}
             
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

AVCaptureDevice is only for Objective-C and everything else I can find is also for Objective-C. Could someone please explain how I could do this in Swift? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show how you are calling them?

Comment: `setTourchModeOn(level:)` is a method on the `AVCaptureDevice` class.

Comment: @ Sweeper I have edited my question to include how I am calling it. For now I am turning the torch on as soon as the app opens.@DanielT. AVCaptureDevice is not for Swift, so how would I turn the torch on. The documentation is showing that these methods are for Swift.

Comment: You can´t put code like that in a body of a SwiftUI View.

Comment: If I put it in a function would it work?

Comment: I am not calling the function, however, at build-time I am getting the errors.

Comment: Where is `lockForConfiguration` defined? It looks like you’re calling a function that doesn’t exist.

Comment: Out of scope may just mean that you're not importing the appropriate framework, or there might be some other problem. A minimal, reproducible example would be very useful here.

Comment: each function belongs to some object. So far you are showing object of type `ContentView ` (which inherits the properties of the object `View`, which doesn't have methods `lockForConfiguration()`, `setTorchModeOn(1.0)`. You need to create an object of type `AVCaptureDevice`, which has these methods. It has nothing to do with Swift / Objective-C. Just plain simple OOP concepts. Please learn them before wandering into application implementation

Comment: @Caleb Alright, I'll modify to show an entire script.

Comment: Also, when you say “AVCaptureDevice is only for ObjectiveC” I’m not sure what you mean? It is part of iOS. And can be used with Swift or ObjectiveC.

Comment: Hey, please can you answer. Where are you defining `lockForConfiguration` function? At the moment your code will not compile because your code is not valid.

Comment: @jjquirckart, I cannot make a object of AVCaptureDevice, as that is once again not in scope. It seems that AVCaptureDevice is not in SwiftUI, which is what I am using.

Comment: @Caleb The documentation is showing that lockForConfiguration is pre-defined

Comment: Please show the code you are writing to try and create the avcapturedevice. You can read the docs here… https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice

Comment: @Fogmeister AVCapture device is seemingly not in scope, so I cannot reference it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an `AVCaptureDevice` instance to call the methods on.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import AVKit

class CaptureSession: ObservableObject {
    lazy var device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var session = CaptureSession()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .onTapGesture {
                turnTorchOn()
            }
    }
    
    func turnTorchOn() {
        do {
            let device = session.device
            try device?.lockForConfiguration()
            defer { device?.unlockForConfiguration() }
            try device?.setTorchModeOn(level: 1.0)
        } catch {
            print("Can't turn torch on, check device has LED flash!")
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, we're getting the default rear camera for the device and (assuming it has a torch) are setting that specific device to turn on when we tap the label.
Because SwiftUI views can be redrawn at any point, we need to make the `device` lives as long as the view is on screen, so we're persisting it in a `StateObject`.

Comment: Although, how do I view if the torch really turned on in the simulator?

Comment: @SimplyDev This will only work on real device, I don't think the simulator is able to tell you if the flash is on or not.

Comment: @SimplyDev You could test for `device.isTorchActive`.
However, I would guess that in the simulator `device.isTorchAvailable` or `device.hasTorch` will probably return `false` in the first place (which you should test for, before trying to turn on the torch).

So, as @BradleyMackey said, you will probably need a physical device to test the torch.